# Can I render a .html and a .pdf presentation in the same .qmd?

Tags: html, r, reveal.js, quarto

I have been working with `Quarto` in RStudio to do some presentations.

I like to do the presentations with `revealjs` and than convert the `.html` output to `.pdf` to send to my students.

Can I render both formats at the same time?

```r
---
title: "R and RStudio"
author: "RTheodoro"
institute: "USP"
format: 
   revealjs:
     logo: img/usp_logo.png
     slide-number: true
     show-slide-number: all
     preview-links: auto
     width: 1280
     height: 720
     theme: default
editor: visual
execute:
  echo: true
---

## What is R?

-   R is.....
```

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try the [`{renderthis}`](https://jhelvy.github.io/renderthis/) package to print the html output as pdf of your quarto slides which will preserve the slide format and styles.

---

**quarto_render.qmd**

```
---
title: "R and RStudio"
author: "RTheodoro"
institute: "USP"
format: 
   revealjs:
     # logo: img/usp_logo.png
     slide-number: true
     show-slide-number: all
     preview-links: auto
     width: 1280
     height: 720
     theme: default
execute:
  echo: true
---

## What is R?

-   R is.....

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a 
finished presentation. To learn more about Quarto presentations 
see <https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/>.
```

---

Then simply render this `quarto_render.qmd` file as you do, by clicking the `render` button in Rstudio, which will create an html file `quarto_render.html` in your working directory. Then from the console, run this command,

```
renderthis::to_pdf("quarto_render.html")
```

Which will create a pdf file `quarto_render.pdf` with slide format in your working directory.

Comment: Thank you, `renderthis` looks awesome, it converts to a wide variety of types.

Answer (score 2):

I just did this and pressed "Render" in RStudio and it generated the pdf and the html. Is that what you mean?

```
---
title: "R and RStudio"
author: "RTheodoro"
institute: "USP"
format: 
  revealjs:
     logo: img/usp_logo.png
     slide-number: true
     show-slide-number: all
     preview-links: auto
     width: 1280
     height: 720
     theme: default
  pdf: default
editor: visual
execute:
  echo: true
---

## What is R?

-   R is.....
```

[image: Render]

Comment: Almost there! In this way I lost the presentation format.. I mean, the "slides".

Comment: are you referring to the slide number 1/2 on the top right corner of the html? I do have them...

Comment: When I do it, I have just the texts in pages. Like a word document. Not in the presentation format.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work in line with previous answer from [shafee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73515629/4961292), but had to add an empty `styles.css` file to the working directory for `pagedown::chrome_print()` to not error on not finding the css file.